# Citadel on Raspberry Pi didn´t work ( c_default_cal_zone is empty)

Tags: email, raspbian

After configuring the *citadel-server* the message

> citserver[1762]: configuration setting c_default_cal_zone is empty,
>   but must not - check your config! will appear.

Remove/reinstall both, Raspian an Citadel can´t solve the Problem. Manually create the directory will also not help

Is there an important step which i have forgotten?

(Sorry for the bad english :-) )

Comment: Manually created the directory where exactly?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

After install your citadel server you have to check your config with

```
sendcommand conf listval
```

after that you will see c_default_cal_zone|. ,configure that with

```
sendcommand "CONF PUTVAL|c_default_cal_zone|timezone"
```

where timezone could be in this format Europe/London

Answer (score 0):

The defalut_cal_zone errror is gone, but the error messages:

> Sep 23 19:34:33 mail citserver[1324]: Cannot create
>   /etc/citadel/netconfigs/7: Is a directory

and

> Sep 23 19:36:40 mail citserver[1483]: Posting crash message

is written to the log.

The login on the webinterface is  not possible, because after click the "Login" Button "Please Wait" will displayed a long time.....

Comment: So what is the answer exactly?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.